# server side validation in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

In asp.net, we have validations for textboxes but these validations are client side using javascript. If a user disables javascript in their browser and visit my website, validations will not work.

Does anybody have another idea?

Comment: Your title has the right idea... validate input server-side.  Client-side validation is nothing more than a UI helper, it does not prevent invalid data.  Only server-side validation can do that.  As a rule of thumb you should never trust any data a client sends you, always check your inputs when they reach the server.

Comment: @Majid by the way there is a difference between *java* and *javascript*

Comment: See [ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in the fact that you cannot rely on client side validation alone. Personally I would invest my time into a one size fits all solution. I really like [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) as it will perform the server side validation as well as automatically generate the client side as well. Very configurable and implemented bu simply adding attributes to your classes.

Answer (score 3):

This is where the [Page.Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx) method and more importantly, the [Page.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx) property come in.

You can do server side something like this

```
 if (Page.IsValid)
 {
   // your code
 }
```

The Validate method is fired automatically by controls that have the `CausesValidation` property set to true.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/03/15/page-isvalid-and-validate.aspx) is breif explanation of this.

Comment: You can use the Validation controls from the VS toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Validation on the client side improves  user experience (they get instant feedback on problem areas), but the validation on the server side is the one that really matters for keeping your data clean. You often need to do both types of validation in most cases.